# R:plot y axis gridlines half way between tickmarks

Tags: r, plot

I can plot a chart with gridlines:

```
df <-data.frame(x=c(1:100),y=runif(100))
plot(df$x,df$y,type="o")
grid (lty = 6,col = "grey")
```

But how can I add extra y gridlines halfway between the y axis tickmarks?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Without changing the number of tickmarks you mean?

Comment: Yes keeping the same y axis tickmarks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work in general, independent of the plot y-axis you put into it.

```
df <-data.frame(x=c(1:100),y=runif(100))
par(lab=c())
plot(df$x,df$y,type="o")

#first draw X gridlines
grid (nx = NULL, ny = NA, lty = 6,col = "grey")

#then draw y gridlines with abline 
Yticks <- axTicks(2)
doublegrid <- c(seq(min(Yticks), max(Yticks), by=(max(Yticks)-min(Yticks))/((length(Yticks)-1)*2)))
abline(h=doublegrid, lty = 6,col = "grey")
```

Answer (score 0):

By 'y axis tickmarks', do you mean those marks with numbers? If so,

```
df <-data.frame(x=c(1:100),y=runif(100))
plot(df$x,df$y,type="o")    
grid(lty = 6,col = "grey", nx=NULL, ny=NULL)
```

Otherwise,

```
abline(h=0.1*0:36, col="gray")
```

would be sufficient?